# Particle system that forms a Text in Blender 2.81

Tags: animation, physics, text-object

I want to make a particle system rain down particles that form a text on the ground of my scene.

How would you do this in Blender 2.81 ?

There are many tutorials using old versions of blender but I am after the steps to set this up in 2.81

Comment: Try converting a text to a mesh, make it transparent, and add a particle system to it.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail in doing this?